# Why GAN use adversarial MinMax formulation rather than Min formulation?

Tags: neural-networks, gan, domain-adaptation

For generative adversarial neural network, originally Goodfellow used a MinMax formulation as $\text{Min}_D\text{Max}_G \mathbb{E}_{real}logD(x) dx+ \mathbb{E}_{fake}(1-D(G(z)))dz$. As long as the generator $G$ is fixed, the optimal discriminator $D$ is explicit. My question is, as we have a clear understanding of $D$, why not just minimize the Jenson-Shannon divergence as a Min formulation, which is equivalent to the MinMax formulation?

BTW, other researchers raised a similar framework called [f-GAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00709.pdf), which replaces the Jenson-Shannon divergence by other $f$-divergence. They also adopted the MinMax formulation, rather than minimizing the divergence directly. Why MinMax formulation is more popular here than Min formulation in these works?

Comment: The Wassertein GAN (specially this post https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/08/20/from-GAN-to-WGAN.html by Lilian Weng) helped me a lot to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not directly minimize the Jensen-Shannon divergence between the generator and empirical distribution? Because it's intractable to compute. The marginal distribution $p(x) = \int p(x|z)p(z) dz$ is very hard to work with, computationally.

Comment: Not contradicting what you said, but a connection can be established: [GANs loss function is exactly the JS divergence when the discriminator is optimal](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/08/20/from-GAN-to-WGAN.html#what-does-the-loss-function-represent)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just figured this out days ago while trying to implement the algorithm.